# Alternative to Load Data Inline

Tags: c#, mysql, multidimensional-array, load-data-infile

I've been trying to speed up the way customer records are added to a C#/MySQL application I've put together. My application relies heavily on arrays of two dimensional strings (string[,]) and to this point I've built customized functions that produce insert statements and handle them in groups of forty or a time (separated by semicolons). I just discovered the LOAD DATA INFILE command and it is a lot simpler, a lot faster, and I can use the REPLACE password to set whether to update existing records or not. I could export the arrays to a CSV file and then upload them into the appropriate tables using LOAD DATA INFILE. However, this seems awfully mettlesome and I have to believe there is some way to either tweak LOAD DATA INLINE or to use a different command that works similarly that I could use to either upload a two dimensional array or a formatted string printout of this array without having to export to a file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Generate an XML blob, then have SQL Server parse the XML using xquery so you can bulk load data. Much simpler than LOAD DATA INFILE.